I am using ADO boards for Application Lifecycle Management. I want to display Sonarqube and veracode metrics in the ADO dashboard
I am using ADO boards for Application Lifecycle Management. I want to display Sonarqube and veracode metrics in the ADO dashboard
There are no inbuilt widgets in the dashboard that pulls the information from Veracode and Sonarqube. Is there a workaround that could be employed using the existing default widgets or is there any widget that can take custom code to pull and display metrics information from Sonarqube and vercode. I don't have admin privilege and will not be able to create new apps
Expectation is to add default widget that can take custom code to pull and display metrics information from Sonarqube and vercode. I don't have admin privilege and will not be able to create new apps

There is an extension "kamextension" provides the widget to show the SonarQube Quality Gate status for a project. You can try it.
For Veracode, there is no available extension found. I only found the extension "Veracode". It is mainly for Azure Pipelines.

